# iframe fading page length issue

Tags: html, jquery

Hi so I am fading my iframe into the page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("#doneimg").fadeIn(500);
});//]]>  
</script>

<div style="display: none;" id="doneimg">
        <iframe src="http://om-p.com" width="90%" height="400" name="SELFHTML_in_a_box">
<p>Ihr Browser kann leider keine eingebetteten Frames anzeigen:
Sie k&ouml;nnen die eingebettete Seite &uuml;ber den folgenden Verweis
aufrufen: <a href="../../../index.htm">SELFHTML</a></p>
</iframe>
    </div>
```

but the problem is that the page loads like if there were no element
so the page length is very small and as soon as the frame has started to fadein increases.

So how can I make the page not change its length but rather have it constant fromt he start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change `display: none;` to `visibility: hidden`:

```
<div style="visibility: hidden;" id="doneimg">
```

Then animate the `opacity`:

```
$("#doneimg").css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);
```

(Since the ordinary `show` and `fadeIn` are using the *display* they won't "work" anymore)

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/899Gh/1/).